# Overlay a DIV on <Object type="text/html"> in IE 8

Tags: html, text, internet-explorer-8, overlap

I am not able to overlap a DIV over Embedded Text file in IE-8. This works in IE-9, Firefox. I have tried using `WMODE-Transaprent,Opaque` and `Z-Index` properties.

Following is my code.

```
<object data="abc.txt" type="text/html" width="300" height="200" > </object>

<div id="div1" style=" background:green; position:absolute; width:100%; height:100%; top:0px; left:0px; filter:alpha(opacity=50)"></div>
```

If I try to embed a `.WAV` or `.SWF` file, the `DIV` is overlayed in IE-8, but the same does not happen with `text/html`.